# Can I insert via a view, and convert data types?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I want to insert into a table, but the tool I am using does not support the data type. Specifically, I want to use Azure Data Factory to insert a `geometry` data type into a Microsoft SQL Server table.

Is there a way of performing this insert using, for example, a WKT string such a `'POINT(100 100)'`, and have this automatically converted within SQL Server to the geometry data type? Could I do this via a view or some kind of stored procedure or trigger?

Comment: Ypu can't have it "automatically" converted, no. You can't pass something like an object and have SQL Server infer the data type from that and implicitly convert it to the data type you want. To `INSERT` a `geometry` value, you should be passing a `geometry` data type value. What you should really be asking is how you achieve that with the application you are using.

Comment: I don't mind creating the code in the SQL Server environment such as a stored procedure or on-insert trigger

Comment: Perhaps you could use [Point (geography Data Type)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geography/point-geography-data-type?view=sql-server-ver15), as you can make parameterised calls to it. For example `geography::Point(@Lat, @Long, @SRID)`.

Comment: That data type isn't available in Azure Data Factory.

Comment: Then best I can suggest is that you convert the geometry value to a `varbinary` value outside of ADF, and the  insert that into a `varbinary` value; as `geometry` values *are* stored as `varbinary` values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can achieve what I want with a view and a trigger:

```
create table [phil].[test_geo]
(   [uid] NUMERIC(12,0), 
    [coords] geometry
)

create view [phil].[test_geo_string] as
select [uid], [coords].STAsText()
from [phil].[test_geo]

create trigger [INSTEADOF_TR_I_test_geo_string]
ON [phil].[test_geo_string]
INSTEAD OF INSERT AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO [phil].[test_geo] (  [uid], [coords] )
    SELECT  I.[uid], geometry::STGeomFromText(I.[coords_string], 27700) 
    FROM INSERTED I
END
```

Apologies for any typos, as I am working over an air-gap.